# building wine on mac

Tags: wine

I'm not really a big fan of macports or any package manager that exists for Mac; Im more of a compile from source guy. Has anyone here tried compiling wine for OSX so that I can execute exe files on my OSX(10.6)?

Are there any alternatives for wine that you would suggest?

Comment: Package managers also build from source ;) The advantage is that they leave your system in a clean state... have a look at Homebrew: http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like what you're looking for: http://code.google.com/p/osxwinebuilder/